Как получить данные "дд.мм.ггг" из поля <input type="date"> в <span>?
Три вопроса.
Есть поле <input  type="date">

Как при выборе определенной даты получить?

<span>дд</span>
<span>мм</span>
<span>гггг</span>


Как настроить это поле чтобы был выбор дата "С" и дата "ПО" и, соответственно, получить

<span id="from">дд</span>
<span id="from">мм</span>
<span id="from">гггг</span>

<span id="till">дд</span>
<span id="till">мм</span>
<span id="till">гггг</span>


Можно ли как-то в <input  type="date"> отражать еще и время чч.мм.сс. и, также, получать данные

<span>дд</span>
<span>мм</span>
<span>гггг</span>
<span>чч</span>
<span>мм</span>

Заранее спасибо

<label>Дата С: <input type="date" id="dateFrom" onchange="displayDateRangeParts()"></label>
<label>Дата ПО: <input type="date" id="dateTill" onchange="displayDateRangeParts()"></label>

<div>
    <span id="fromDay"></span>/<span id="fromMonth"></span>/<span id="fromYear"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="tillDay"></span>/<span id="tillMonth"></span>/<span id="tillYear"></span>
</div>

<script>
function displayDateRangeParts() {
    const dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
    const dateTill = document.getElementById("dateTill").value;

    if (dateFrom) {
        const [fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay] = dateFrom.split("-");
        document.getElementById("fromDay").innerText = fromDay;
        document.getElementById("fromMonth").innerText = fromMonth;
        document.getElementById("fromYear").innerText = fromYear;
    }

    if (dateTill) {
        const [tillYear, tillMonth, tillDay] = dateTill.split("-");
        document.getElementById("tillDay").innerText = tillDay;
        document.getElementById("tillMonth").innerText = tillMonth;
        document.getElementById("tillYear").innerText = tillYear;
    }
}
</script>


<input type="datetime-local"> поддерживает формат YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

